# Does "laptop memory" mean SO-DIMM?

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

I want to upgrade RAM of my laptop, a [Lenovo Ideapad Y510](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/lenovo-ideapad-y510/4507-3121_7-32815684.html). The form factor of RAM given here is "SO DIMM 200-pin".

I have two options, [first](http://www.ebay.in/itm/TRANSCEND-2-GB-DDR2-LAPTOP-RAM-667-MHZ-2-GB-RAM-/200783351415?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item2ebf9ece77) and [second](http://www.ebay.in/itm/Memory-Master-2-GB-DDR2-667-MHz-PC2-5300-Notebook-SODIMM-Memory-Module-MMN-JPL-/270949726803?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item3f15dcba53). My question is: both are of type DDR2 2GB 667MHz but the second one explicitly mentions "SO DIMM" while first does not.

Will the first one fit in my machine?

Comment: Sorry but shopping recommendations are off topic here on SU. Please read the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: He is asking for shopping advice, but his real question is 'What is the difference between SO-DIMM and DIMM.'

Comment: @Diogo: I am just want to know the difference between both of these ram so that I can go with correct one.

Comment: @user142485: Thanks. That's what I actually mean.

Comment: @Sandy You should make the edits so it does not sound like you are asking for shopping advice.

Comment: I edited the question so that it hopefully sounds less like asking for shopping advice, and focuses more on what memory will work in the computer in question.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: I have edited question again. Hope it is making more sense now. Any further changes are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, SODIMM is for laptop and DIMM is for desktop. Go with the SODIMM. The reason why there is a difference between RAM for laptop and desktop is electrical, heat and economcial.

Comment: but if you see both listenings both rams are for laptops.

Comment: @Sandy One says 'Laptop Ram' which is slang for small outline dimm like I said above.

Comment: I have never seen a desktop using this type of RAM - maybe the new small form factor hard drives but they are designed for different reasons. Any way, this is now a shopping question so it's up to you.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is **NOT** one of trying to figure out the difference between the two RAM offering.  The issue here is that *both* are eBay listings, and not subject to quality control as far as what the person selling the product actually types when they list the product.

Yes.  Laptops use SO-DIMM memory.  And... if you were to go by the pictures provided for both listings, then BOTH of the items are SO-DIMM, as they are both the same size (physically), have the notch in the same place, both made for laptops, etc.

If it's made for a laptop, it's SO-DIMM.  If it's made for a laptop, this does not mean that the person listing the memory for sale is smart enough to add that (when it's not visible on the packaging).

Comment: "If it's made for a laptop, it's SO-DIMM" if I am not interpreting your words wrong then you mean to say both are SO-DIMM.

Comment: @Sandy you are correct.  If the picture is real, and the seller is not trying to scam you, then they are both so-dimm

Answer (score 3):

SO stands for 'small outline' which is what is used in most laptops and some desktops (quite a few Macs). Try Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM .

Answer (score 1):

SODIMM are usually meant for laptops. DIMM won't even fit in the slot provided in the motherboard. Also if you want to select a good RAM, make sure the frequency matches your previously installed RAM and suits your motherboard